# 'no such file to load -- net/ssh' from rails Controller on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-8.04, net-ssh

I have a very simple controller:

```
require 'net/ssh'

class MyController < ApplicationController
    def foo
        render :text => 'bar'
    end
end
```

But when I request http://server:3000/my/foo I get:

```
MissingSourceFile in MyController#foo 
no such file to load -- net/ssh
```

The gem is installed

```
> gem list net-ssh

*** LOCAL GEMS ***
net-ssh (2.0.11)
```

Also, I tried require 'net/ssh' in IRB, and it works.

MyController works fine on Windows, but fail on Ubuntu.

What can be wrong?

Comment: This error occurs on a fresh install of Mac OS Leopard - I have had the exact same issue trying to use the default net-sftp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:

[Rails Gem Dependencies and Plugin Errors](http://www.webficient.com/2008/07/11/ruby-on-rails-gem-dependencies-and-plugin-errors)

This is also worth watching:

[Railscasts: Gem Dependencies](http://railscasts.com/episodes/110-gem-dependencies)

Comment: Thank you! I added [config.gem 'net-ssh', :lib => "net/ssh"] 
into environment.rb and executed [rake gems:install]. Now it works.

Answer (score 3):

In a project I am working on we have used the config/environment.rb file to hold the gem require stuff. So

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  # ...
  config.gem 'net-ssh'
  config.gem 'daemons'
  config.gem 'slave'
  config.gem 'vpim'
  config.gem 'json'
  # ...
end
```

I think you will require 'net-ssh' rather than 'net/ssh'. However we did run into a problem where have a hyphen in the name of the gem led to failures. Then we had to do

```
  config.gem 'Ruby-IRC', :lib => 'IRC'
```

so that version maybe required for you. So that would be

```
  config.gem 'net-ssh', :lib => 'net/ssh'
```

Answer (score 2):

in case of rails 3.0
this solution if OK. 
add this  in the yourapp/Gemfile,

```
gem 'net-ssh
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, since it's a stand alone ruby app, I only needed to require rubygems.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Dr Nic's ''gemsonrails'' and load vendored gems as plugins, check: 
http://gemsonrails.rubyforge.org

Answer (score 0):

I think, the original problem was that I used normal user instead of root:

```
$ gem install net-ssh
  WARNING:  Installing to ~/.gem since /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 and
            /usr/bin aren't both writable.
  WARNING:  You don't have /home/alex/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin in your PATH,
            gem executables will not run.
```

So, I guess, rails could not find this gem.