# Error referencing installed Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby, ssh, rubygems, sftp

Can anyone help with an odd Ruby Gem problem I'm having - note I've installed many gems in the past and never seen this.

I've downloaded the net-ssh and net-sftp gems using the following commands:

```
sudo gem install net-ssh
sudo gem install net-sftp
```

both installed successfully. However when I reference the files within my code I get the following error:

```
./workers/ffmpeg_worker.rb:6:in `require': no such file to load -- net/ssh (LoadError)
    from ./workers/ffmpeg_worker.rb:6
    from ./workers/tests/test_ffmpeg_worker.rb:3:in `require'
    from ./workers/tests/test_ffmpeg_worker.rb:3
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/...]
```

Note when I do:

```
gem list --local
```

The gems are listed as such:

```
net-scp (1.0.2)
net-sftp (2.0.2, 1.1.0)
net-ssh (2.0.15, 1.1.2)
net-ssh-gateway (1.0.1)
```

Any clues?

Comment: did you `require 'rubygems'`?

Comment: Nope, I haven't for any of the other gems - see my "fix" below

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915673/no-such-file-to-load-net-ssh-from-rails-controller-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I see this sort of thing, it usually comes down to having more than one Ruby installed on the machine (which means more than one gem location, etc.), and different apps or environments getting confused about which one to load.

Check for that first.  If that isn't the answer, do a `gem which net/ssh` to see where RubyGems thinks the gem is installed -- make sure it isn't the local user's **.gems** directory or something.

If neither one solves the mystery, stick some debugging code into your worker script and have it output its load path (**$:**) so you can see where it's looking.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out - but it seemed to be fixed by defining RUBYOPT as described in another question.